# How to handle alert after video recording duration reached in Swift?

Tags: swift, video, camera

I am trying to limit video recording to 10 seconds in Swift. The problem is when the duration is reached, iPhone will end up with an error like alert. How can I handle this so that it alerts are not shown?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController{
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = context.coordinator
    picker.sourceType = sourceType
    picker.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    picker.videoMaximumDuration = 10
    return picker
}
```

This is the end result when time reached:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can change picker.allowsEditing = false to hide the alert message showing at the bottom i.e., VIDEO_TOO_LONG_TITLE - Please select a smaller clip from this video.

Comment: Would you mind to use the tilde to differentiate the code from the text? 
I would do it but it shows that the edit's queue is full.